# ActionBarDrawerToggle is not shown on Toolbar using android-support-v7:21 library

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library, android-toolbar

Trying to implement new drawer toggle from android-support-v7:21 library, but it is not shown.
Code snippet:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initToolbar();
    }

    private void initToolbar() {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                mToolbar,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close
        );
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call `syncState` method on `mDrawerToggle` in activity's `onPostCreate` method:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
```

Comment: allright... even i was missing this function call. Had been looking for over an hour for the right answer.thanks.

But really, the hamburger animation is no point now that the toolbar is covered up by the navigation drawer.